# customising the parse return value, retaining unnamed terminals

Tags: parsing, grammar, raku

Consider the grammar:

```
TOP ⩴ 'x' Y 'z'
Y ⩴ 'y'
```

Here's how to get the exact value `["TOP","x",["Y","y"],"z"]` with various parsers (not written manually, but generated from the grammar):

*xyz__Parse-Eyapp.eyp*

```
%strict
%tree

%%
start:
    TOP { shift; use JSON::MaybeXS qw(encode_json); print encode_json $_[0] };
TOP:
    'x' Y 'z'   { shift; ['TOP', (scalar @_) ? @_ : undef] };
Y:
    'y' { shift; ['Y', (scalar @_) ? @_ : undef] };

%%
```

---

*xyz__Regexp-Grammars.pl*

```
use 5.028;
use strictures;
use Regexp::Grammars;
use JSON::MaybeXS qw(encode_json);
print encode_json $/{TOP} if (do { local $/; readline; }) =~ qr{
<nocontext:>
<TOP>
<rule: TOP>
    <[anon=(x)]> <[anon=Y]> <[anon=(z)]>
    <MATCH=(?{['TOP', $MATCH{anon} ? $MATCH{anon}->@* : undef]})>
<rule: Y>
    <[anon=(y)]>
    <MATCH=(?{['Y', $MATCH{anon} ? $MATCH{anon}->@* : undef]})>

}msx;
```

---

Code elided for the next two parsers. With Pegex, the functionality is achieved by inheriting from [Pegex::Receiver](http://p3rl.org/Pegex::Receiver). With Marpa-R2, the [customisation of the return value is quite limited](http://p3rl.org/Marpa::R2::Semantics#Array-descriptor-actions), but nested arrays are possible out of the box with a configuration option.

I have demonstrated that the desired customisation is possible, although it's not always easy or straight-forward. These pieces of code attached to the rules are run as the tree is assembled.

---

The [parse](https://docs.perl6.org/parse) method returns nothing but nested Match objects that are unwieldy. They do not retain the unnamed terminals! (Just to make sure what I'm talking about: these are the two pieces of data at the RHS of the `TOP` rule whose values are `'x'` and `'z'`.) Apparently only data springing forth from named declarators are added to the tree.

Assigning to the match variable (analog to how it works in Regexp-Grammars) seems to have no effect. Since the terminals do no make it into the match variable, [actions](https://docs.perl6.org/Actions) don't help, either.

In summary, here's the grammar and ordinary parse value:

```
grammar {rule TOP { x <Y> z }; rule Y { y };}.parse('x y z')
```

How do you get the value `["TOP","x",["Y","y"],"z"]` from it? You are not allowed to change the shape of rules because that would potentially spoil user attached semantics, otherwise anything else is fair game. I still think the key to the solution is the match variable, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a full answer, but the [Match.chunks method](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match#method_chunks) gives you a few of the input string tokenized into captured and non-captured parts.

It does, however, does not give you the ability to distinguish between non-capturing literals in the regex and implicitly matched whitespace.

You could circumvent that by adding positional captures, and use [Match.caps](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match#method_caps)

```
my $m = grammar {rule TOP { (x) <Y> (z) }; rule Y { (y) }}.parse('x y z');

sub transform(Pair $p) {
    given $p.key {
        when Int { $p.value.Str }
        when Str { ($p.key, $p.value.caps.map(&transform)).flat }
    }
}

say $m.caps.map(&transform);
```

This produces

```
(x (Y y) z)
```

so pretty much what you wanted, except that the top-level `TOP` is missing (which you'll likely only get in there if you hard-code it).

Note that this doesn't cover all edge cases; for example when a capture is quantified, `$p.value` is an Array, not a match object, so you'll need another level of `.map` in there, but the general idea should be clear.